# files not loading in HTML text area

Tags: javascript, html, file, textarea

I am trying to load 3 files from a `file/JOHN` directory where files are already present.

Files are in the following format. Let's say they are in the following location (inside `file/JOHN` folder):  `C:/john/file/JOHN/`

```
file1_1555077233.csv
file2_1555077233.csv 
file3_1555077233.csv
```

Since I am testing it on my Windows machine, I have it at this location `C:/john/file/JOHN/`. However, eventually, on the RHEL server, it's going to be like this `/srv/users/JOHN/` so I am using user directory on Windows machine for my testing purpose.

Files aren't showing in the text area. However, text area shows after 1 sec as soon as I click on the button.What am I doing wrong?

Below code displays a text area after 1 second as soon as `Download File` button is clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>LoadFiles</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="built/style.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var interval;
        function loadFiles() {
            interval = setInterval(displayTextArea, 1000);


        }
        function displayTextArea() {
              console.log(new Date() + " ");

              document.getElementById("downloadtextArea").innerHTML =
                 '<textarea maxlength="500" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>'; 


                const requests = [
                  'file1_1555077233.csv',
                  'file2_1555077233.csv ',
                  'file3_1555077233.csv'
                ].map(file => {

                 return fetch('file:///C:/john/file/JOHN/' + file)
                    .then(response => response.text())
                    .catch(console.error)
                })

                Promise.all(requests)
                  .then(contents => contents.join('\n'))
                  .then(content => {

                    //container.innerHTML = `<textarea>${content}</textarea>`
                    content.innerHTML = `<textarea>${content}</textarea>`
                  })


                clearInterval(interval);




            }






    </script>
</head>
<body>


<button id="downloadFileButton" onclick="loadFiles()">Download File</button>
<div id ="downloadtextArea"></div>


</body>
</html>
```

**Troubleshooting Step I performed:**

Copied the following path in the browser:

`file:///C:/john/file/JOHN/file1_1555077233.csv`  and I saw the file

Comment: `console.log(contents)` what do you see

Comment: @IsaacVidrine  I saw the name of the columns printing 3 times which are present in the CSV file `"Column1","Column2","Column3","Column4"`. I used ` console.log(content);` just above this line `content.innerHTML = `<textarea>${content}</textarea>``

Comment: `content` is the data from the response, so of course `content.innerHTML` will do nothing. You need something like `document.getElementById('mycontentarea').innerHTML = content`

Comment: @Issac Vidrine Ok. Could you tell me where exactly you were asking me to put `console.log(contents)` in the above code? Also, where should this `document.getElementById('mycontentarea').innerHTML = content` go? Thanks

Comment: `content` is the response from your request to load the files. You should log out their values to see what they are. Once you get the data you need, you append that data to the markup on the page.

Comment: @IsaacVidrine Thanks. Actually, I am looking to display 3 files in the text area and not the content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to set `innerHTML` on your response data, not on a `DOM` element.

In your `displayTextArea()` function:

```
function displayTextArea() {
  console.log(new Date() + " ");
  const requests = [
    'file1_1555077233.csv',
    'file2_1555077233.csv ',
    'file3_1555077233.csv'
  ].map(file => {
    return fetch('file:///C:/john/file/JOHN/' + file)
    .then(response => response.text())
    .catch(console.error)
  })

  Promise.all(requests)
  .then(contents => contents.join('\n'))
  .then(content => {
    document.getElementById('downloadtextArea').innerHTML = `<textarea>${content}</textarea>`
  })
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works but it's showing the contents of the file in the textarea. I believe 3 times. Is it possible to show just the 3 files in the text area?

Comment: Isn't what you wanted to show the content of the files in a textarea?

Comment: Nope. I would like to show 3 files inside text area. After this, I would implement a functionality where user can click on a button (which will show along with text area) and download the files in zip format.

Comment: What do you mean you want to show 3 files? Thats what the content is. Are you saying you just want to display their names? Please be more specific with the problem.

Comment: I would like to show `file1_1555077233.csv`, `file2_1555077233.csv` and `file3_1555077233.csv` in the text area. Not the content of all the three files. Since, I plan on having a button just below the text area, when user clicks on that button, those 3 files will get converted to zip format and user can save it. That's my plan. Please let me know if I can answer more questions. thanks

Comment: Okay so..... why are you even making a request to load the file contents? If what you want is to just show the names, you already know the names... you have them set static in the code `const requests = [
    'file1_1555077233.csv',
    'file2_1555077233.csv ',
    'file3_1555077233.csv'
  ]`

Comment: Honestly, the requirements as you are describing them seem rather ridiculous

Comment: Could you tell me whether it is possible to have the names of the 3 files displayed in the text area along with the contents as well? When I say `along with contents`, I mean the file should contain all the contents and doesn't mean to display the contents of the file in text area. In this way, when a user clicks on the download button (which I plan to show below text area), user can download all the 3 files and when user will open the files, they will see the content inside it.

Comment: Continued... OR should I accomplish the task of displaying the file names separately and task of downloading the files from the location separately?

Comment: *I mean the file should contain all the contents and doesn't mean to display the contents of the file in text area*... that makes no sense man. A `textarea` does one thing... displays `text`. So the values in the text area arent files, they are nothing but text. If the only point of this is to allow a user to download a file, why would you need a `textarea` for? Just give them a button that shows the name of the file and allows them to download it.

Comment: The only reason for a `textarea` would be to allow a user to edit the content of a file.

Comment: @Issac Vidrine That makes sense. Thanks again. The whole reason of showing text area after certain interval of time is because the files are not going to be present in the directory immediately.
Hence, my code will keep on looking for the files every 1 sec or 5 seconds. As soon as the files are there, they will see 3 file names over there and then I can have them download all the 3 files from the location of the directory in zip format. 

If I display 3 buttons with file names, probably they will have to click 3 buttons and download the files individually, which I am not looking for.

Comment: Okay, so just make it 1 button that downloads all three. And from what I understand, there is probably a much better solution to what you are trying to solve as your end goal. You probably don't need to keep making requests to check if files exists.

Comment: @Issac Vidrine Yeah, that sounds like a good idea. Thanks very much ! Any ideas on other solutions? Emailing to the user or me is one option I think as soon as file exists on the location, but I guess this might require some email related settings on the server

Comment: @John, when user clicks button to download, make a request to try and download, if the file doesn't exist at that point, just display a notification on the page saying "file doesnt exist in location yet" or something

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I will use that approach!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why the text area is showing after 1 second is that you've set an interval of 1 second in the `loadfiles()` method.

Can you specify what error is displayed in the console after clicking the Download button? 
Is it below error?
Fetch API cannot load `file:///C:/john/file/JOHN/file1_1555077233.csv`. URL scheme must be "http" or "https" for CORS request.

Comment: Thanks @VrushtiJoshi. It's loading the contents of the file after I made the changes mentioned by Issac in his answer below. However, I want to load the 3 files in the text area. I have disabled the CORS thing in my Firefox using `about:config` option for my testing purpose since eventually, I will be getting these files on the RHEL server.